# In ActiveMQ clustering, how to find the consumer who picked a particular message or set of messages?

Tags: activemq-classic, cluster-computing

We have set of queues and camel routes have been written to consume messages from the queue - queues live in an ActiveMQ server and camel routes in Apache Karaf. We have put up a cluster with multiple karaf nodes; problem is that these messages get read by camel routes in different nodes; is there a way to know the consumer who picked a particular message or set of messages? I googled around but did not get any head way so I am here asking your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a combination of:

1. **ActiveMQ [TraceBrokerPathPlugin](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/broker/util/TraceBrokerPathPlugin.html)**: [Configure](http://activemq.apache.org/logging-interceptor.html) this plugin in each node of your cluster. It will append the 'brokerName' to a JMS header in the message as it goes through the nodes.
2. **Enable [Message History](http://camel.apache.org/message-history.html) in Camel Context**: Configure all you camel context to enable message history. It will include an exchange property with a list of *org.apache.camel.MessageHistory* with routing metadata.
3. **Enable [trace](http://camel.apache.org/tracer.html) or implement [EventNotifier](http://camel.apache.org/eventnotifier-to-log-details-about-all-sent-exchanges.html)** to write the information you need into a log file.
4. ***(Optional)* Implement Correlation Identifier** to better identify the flow of your messages within a conversation/transaction.

Comment: interesting, let me try this one out and let you know.

Comment: I could use TraceBrokerPathPlugin and that suffices.

Answer (score 1):

For debugging purposes you can use Hawtio to monitor your Camel nodes and trace the messages consumed by the routes. You can also add logging to your routes on the fly in there.

Answer (score 0):

There is no tracking of consumed messages in ActiveMQ except for advisory messages. The solution is to let each Camel consumer announce that it processed a message somehow. There are tons of way to do that, such as writing to a log file, sending logs to a database, email or whatever depending on frequency and need. Of course, you could write some plugin or similar to ActiveMQ and have it log such information for your need, but that seems awkward.